# How to install mpi4py correctly in windows 8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mpi, mpi4py

I am tying to get the mpi4py package to work, but am getting an error when importing MPI from this package.

I tried the following:

```
pip install mpi4py
```

Then I installed the MSMPI and msmpisdk files and added the paths "C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin" and "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI" to my environment variables.

Now I am trying a test code:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import sys

size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()
rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
name = MPI.Get_processor_name()

sys.stdout.write(
"Hello, World! I am process %d of %d on %s.\n"
% (rank, size, name))
```

Which I saved as hello.py

When I try running this
    python hello.py

the following error occurs on line: from mpi4py import MPI

"ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found"

I am assuming it is from the installation. Am I missing a step in this setup/installation of this package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled everything and started over, but this time I installed the Microsoft MPI stuff first and then did pip install mpi4py. I am not sure how/why, but this fixed my problem.

Comment: hi i followed the same method installed MSMPI followed by SDK and then pip install but still i am getting the same error. I added these to the env MSMPI_BIN, MSMPI_INC, MSMPI_LIB32, MSMPI_LIB64 did you add any extra variables. Also im installing in windows 10

Comment: Hmm, and you added the correct paths? If so I am not sure why it wouldn’t be working. I will see if I can find the tutorial on adding the paths that I followed unless you’re positive you did this part right.

Comment: yes i have verified all the paths also during installation of SDK these were automatically added to the env list. Also I have tried with all the versions of MSMPI from 1.7 to 1.10 but none worked

Comment: And you made sure the other versions were uninstalled before trying the new one? ....I’m not entirely sure why you are still getting the error. If I were you I would try one more time to just uninstall everything and start from scratch installing the mpi sdk stuff first followed by the python stuff. Sorry, I wish I could do more to help!